# spinnaker configuration files precedence documentation?

Tags: spinnaker

Configuration for a particular spinnaker system can be written in a number of different files. Is precedence documentation available?

e.g. for clouddriver:

```
/opt/spinnaker/config/clouddriver.yml  
/opt/spinnaker/config/clouddriver-local.yml  
/opt/clouddriver/config/clouddriver.yml
```

or settings can be in the provider section of

```
/opt/spinnaker/config/spinnaker-local.yml
```

Comment: [This page](http://www.spinnaker.io/v1.0/docs/custom-configuration#section-about-the-different-yaml-files) provides inclusion order for files in `/opt/spinnaker/config`  


So in my case I could write my configs in `/opt/spinnaker/config/clouddriver-local.yml`  


I still don't know the role of `/opt/clouddriver/config/clouddriver.yml` or when I should use the provider section of `/opt/spinnaker/config/spinnaker-local.yml`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post on this very topic a while back, because several users were getting confused:

https://www.travistomsu.com/2016/12/19/configuring-spinnaker/

The gist is that there are various levels of shared settings (with overrides) and service-specific settings (with overrides).

The order of loading looks like:

1. spinnaker.yaml (shared across all services, do not edit - will be overwritten on update)
2. spinnaker-local.yaml (override across all services, editable)
3. service.yaml (service-specific, do not edit)
4. service-local.yaml (override for this particular service, editable)

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment I found the documentation [here](http://www.spinnaker.io/v1.0/docs/custom-configuration#section-about-the-different-yaml-files)

Based on that, even though there is no mention of `/opt/subsystem/config/subsystem.yml` I will go with using `/opt/spinnaker/config/clouddriver-local.yml`